# multiplying a matrix with identity matrix results in some matrix elements to be zero

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `m` which has some `float` numbers. When I multiply it with the Identity matrix, some elements if the resulting matrix becomes zero. Actually, there should be no change in the matrix. Can anyone help me?

[image: 1]

In the above image, **there is no 0.013 in the matrix**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator in numpy corresponds to element-wise product of two arrays. Use the `@` operator for matrix multiplication.

```
m@I
```

Comment: ohh....thankyou verymuch. it actually worked. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped :)